Macros, Code Snippets, or even Keyboard Shortcuts not working in Visual Studio 2008 for C++
I am working in Visual Studio 2008 and cannot update due to constraint of my software compatibility issue. I search everywhere on the Internet, read many posts here as well, but no solution found to deal with Macros, Keyboard Shortcut, or Code Snippets for Visual Studio 2008. I seek help for the C++ language.
Also, I'm struggling to run 'Temporary Macros' even though save after recording.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

I tried to record macros, assign keyboards shortcuts, and try every single things. I hope to find the solution for C++ code to speed up code writing since I have no other options to update to a newer version due to incompatibility for software customization I am working on, because the software supports Visual Studio 2008 only.

First, are you sure it is VS2008 only, and not at least VS2008? Very often an old library saying "requires version X" just means that older versions doesn't work. It doesn't mean that newer versions also doesn't work. (I say this because VS2022 has a percentage-selector in the bottom left corner, so can change font size without macro recordings).

Not sure if the C++ tag is necessary here...

MS stopped supporting VS 2008 about 7 years ago. It is unlikely that anyone can fix some issues on it. So if it somehow does not run well on more modern Windows versions then you probably have to run it on older Windows or VM of older Windows.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
